# Error Exception calling ".ctor" with "2" argument(s)

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-data-explorer

I'm getting below error while running a PowerShell script to connect to the ADX Cluster database.

**Error:**

```
New-Object: /home/anuruddha/kqltest.ps1:10
Line |
  10 |  $kcsb = New-Object Kusto.Data.KustoConnectionStringBuilder ($clusterU …
     |          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Exception calling ".ctor" with "2" argument(s): "The type initializer for 'Kusto.Data.KustoConnectionStringBuilder' threw an exception."
```

**Script:**

```
$packagesRoot = "/home/user/tools/net472"


[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("$packagesRoot\Kusto.Data.dll")


$clusterUrl = "https://testcluster.kusto.windows.net;Fed=True"
$databaseName = "testdb"
$kcsb = New-Object Kusto.Data.KustoConnectionStringBuilder ($clusterUrl, $databaseName)
```

**$Error[0].Exception.GetBaseException()|fl * -Force Output**

```
Line |
   9 |  $kcsb = New-Object Kusto.Data.KustoConnectionStringBuilder ($clusterU …
     |          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Exception calling ".ctor" with "2" argument(s): "The type initializer for 'Kusto.Data.KustoConnectionStringBuilder' threw an exception."



Message        : Could not load file or assembly 'Kusto.Cloud.Platform, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=829a00acde12d551'. The system cannot find the file specified.
                 
FileName       : Kusto.Cloud.Platform, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=829a00acde12d551
FusionLog      : 
TargetSite     : 
Data           : {}
InnerException : 
HelpLink       : 
Source         : 
HResult        : -2147024894
StackTrace     :
```

Comment: The error suggests that a dependent assembly, `Kusto.Cloud.Platform`, cannot be found.

Answer (score 0):

Try passing only the URL to the constructor, then set the initial DB and security settings on the object afterwards:

```
$clusterUrl = "https://testcluster.kusto.windows.net"
$databaseName = "testdb"

$kcsb = New-Object Kusto.Data.KustoConnectionStringBuilder @($clusterUrl)
$kcsb.FederatedSecurity = $true
$kcsb.InitialCatalog = $databaseName
```

Comment: Nope. its not working .
Exception calling ".ctor" with "1" argument(s): "The type initializer for 'Kusto.Data.KustoConnectionStringBuilder' threw an exception."

  11 |  $kcsb.FederatedSecurity = $true
     |  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | The property 'FederatedSecurity' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.

Line |
  12 |  $kcsb.InitialCatalog = $databaseName
     |  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | The property 'InitialCatalog' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.

Comment: @anuruddhas Can you try and inspect the underlying exception? Run `$Error[0].GetBaseException()|fl * -Force` after the error occurs, then paste the output into your post

Comment: Seems that method also unavailable. I'm running these command thorough Azure Cloud shell .  

 Method invocation failed because [System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord] does not contain a method named 'GetBaseException'.

Comment: @anuruddhas Try `$Error[0].Exception.GetBaseException()|fl * -Force`

Comment: Done and output updated in the post